# Upper bound on number of Rows in azure table storage...?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-table-storage, upperbound, azure-diagnostics

I would like to know is there any upper limit for the number of rows in the Azure Table storage.

I am asking this question as I have turned on the diagnostics monitoring and moving the logs to the `WADPerformanceCountersTable`. I noticed that the log are unavailable for the past 15 hrs.

In case, If there is any upper limit for the rows in tables, then might be the storage has stopped accepting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit stated - other than the total number of 100TB within a single storage account.

Everything looks good on http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/support/status/servicedashboard.aspx

If you're on a trial account, then it might be that you've hit the trial limit? If not, then maybe log a request with Azure support.

Comment: Ya, I am using their trial azure pass, might be they have an 'Upper bound'

Comment: No Stuart, I tried manually inserting a row in that table, it accepted. Then might be, there is little problem with the logging.

Comment: The logging data is uploaded direct from the monitor on each of your VMs to your storage. Did anything else change in your app or deployment 15 hours ago?

Comment: No change, in fact I dont even visit that app. Right now I am purely interested only int the logging aspect, so I leave that app running. What else could have gone wrong...? any views..??

Answer (score 2):

There was an Azure Storage outage yesterday afternoon in the North-Central region.  It was not reported on the status dashboard.  Outage lasted for about 1hr from what our service could tell (or from how our service was impacted).  All is back now.

Comment: I use the South East Asia Region - Singapore. The entire app runs on the Azure Trail Pass. I think that would be the probable reason for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know the older logs aren't there? (I wonder if it's an issue with the tool you're using to view them.)

It's correct that there's no limit on the number of rows. If you hit the 100TB limit for a storage account (sounds quite unlikely), what would happen is that new inserts would fail. Old data would never be deleted.